# Regex ending on first not last

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression that stops at the first " not the last one.

For example if I check for '`list:".*"`' and I have a string such as list:"dogs" it will work fine.

But if I have something like list:"dogs" "cats" that regex will catch the whole thing ending at the very last ". But I need to end the first time it sees the closing " after dog. How do I do this?

Comment: You could do it one of two ways, non-greedy `list:".*?"` or greedy `list:"[^"]*"`